# Add a button to show properties inside a graph

Tags: plotting, manipulate, button

I would like to draw the graph of $f(x)=x^{3}-x+2$ next to two buttons named: "Property1" and "Property2" in which when I press "Property1" it shows "f'(1) is positive", while for "Property2" it shows "f'(1)=2".

I am only able to draw my idea as follows:

```
f[x_] = x^3 - x + 2;
f'[x_] = 3*x^2 - 1;
pt1 = Plot[x^3 - 3*x + 1, {x, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> {-2, 6}];
pt2 = Manipulate[p[1], {p, {f, f'}}];
GraphicsRow[{pt1, pt2}]
```

[image]

Could someone give me a help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[st, sign, f, g]
f[x_] := x^3 - x + 2;
g[x_] := x^3 - 3*x + 1;
sign[x_] := Sign[x] /. {-1 -> Negative, _ :> Positive}
st = {StringTemplate["f(``) = <* f[#]*>."],
   StringTemplate["f'(``) is <* sign[f'[#]]*>."]};

pt1 = Plot[g[x], {x, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> {-2, 6}, ImageSize -> 200];
pt2 = Manipulate[st[[p]][x],
   {x, 0, 1},
   {{p, 1}, {1 -> "Property 1", 2 -> "Property 2"}}];

Panel @ Row[{pt1, pt2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You must be a dreamy teacher in any classroom.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to make an animation in the same picture with "Property 3" button, for e.g. making the point M running along the graph of g[x] from (0,1) to (1,-1) once "Property 3" taken action? Thanks.

Comment: @Binjiu, if you want the animation in the manipulate panel, you can define `st = {StringTemplate["f(``) = <* f[#]*>."],
  StringTemplate["f'(``) is <* sign[f'[#]]*>."], 
  Animate[Show[pt1, 
    Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{x, g[x]}]}], {x, 0, 1}, 
   Paneled -> False]}` and `pt2 = Manipulate[p /. {3 -> st[[3]], i_ :> st[[i]][x]},
   {x, 0, 1},
   {{p, 1}, {1 -> "Property 1", 2 -> "Property 2", 
     3 -> "Property 3"}}];` If you want the animation on the left panel, I cannot think of a simple modification of the current answer (maybe you can post it as a separate question).